# Parse content using cURL from a Ajaxed Site

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, curl, web-scraping

I am writing an application using CodeIgniter and I need to parse some content from another site, the problem is that this site is using ajax to load content and the simple cURL method I am using isn't working to fetch such content. (im a little new to this)

I already tried some solutions from here but without success

This is my actual code:

```
class Deuses extends CI_Controller {

    function Deuses() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model("modelo_deuses");
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    function builds($deus_nome){
        $url = 'http://www.smitestuff.com/gods/agni#builds'; 
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest", "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"));
        $html .= curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close ($curl);
        echo $html;
        $data['deuses'] = $this->modelo_deuses->ver($deus_nome);
        $data['skins'] = $this->modelo_deuses->ver_skins($deus_nome);
        $this->load->view('deuses/skins',$data);
    }
}
```

I want to get the content that is loaded into

```
<main id="god_detail"></main>
```

Righw not it is parsing the general content correctly, but without any content from #god_detail (that is what i really need)

So I need a help to find out how to make the cURL thing get into the site and capture the content of the ajax call.

Any help is welcome!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Scrap and scrape are two very different words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `http://www.smitestuff.com/gods/html/agni/content.html` url instead of `http://www.smitestuff.com/gods/agni#builds` you will get all the content of each tabs.